# How to Migrating Lucene to Solr

Tags: web, solr, lucene, migration

I am Japanese and I am using a translator so sorry if my English is strange.

I am working on a website for my job and I am looking for a way to migrate the search function from Lucene to Solr.

Is there any software or other software out there that would make this possible? (Is it distributed on official websites?)

And if not, what means are available? Please let us know how to do this. If you have a similar answer, please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot migrate `Lucene` to `Solr` as `Solr` is built on top of `Lucene`.
`Lucene` is the core search engine library, `Solr` is the search server.

`Apache Lucene` is the base version for the search engine while `Apache Solr` is inherited Lucene with new inbuilt features which Apache Lucene don't provide out of the box.

There are no direct option or tools available for the same.

There are many option available for indexing data to solr.
It all depends on where is your data. like if you have data in database one way is to use `DataImportHandler` of solr to index data in solr.

Please refer the documentation for more options [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/introduction-to-solr-indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will refer to them.

Comment: @Akari, If this answers you question, please accept the same.